# Django Inline formsets with Form wizard¶

Tags: python, django, inline-formset, django-formwizard

I have two models, the second one have a ForeignKeyto the first one.

I'm using Django form wizzard to complet many regrouped fields in separated steps. The problem is when I arrive in the "TeamMember" step, where I'm supposed to let the user enter many members.

I was thinking to use Django Inline formset, but I can not implement it inside my formwizard, I get a

> [u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']

error when I try to display this step.

Here is my implementation, if some one have any idea, it would be really appreciated :).

Don't hesitate to contact me if you need more informations.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Yann

**models.py**

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = name = models.CharField(_(u'Team'), max_length=50))

class TeamMember(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('First name'), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_(u'Last name'), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class FundingRequestFormTeam(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TeamMember
        exclude = ('team',)
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name')

TeamMemberFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Team, TeamMember)
```

**urls.py**

```
team_wizard = TeamWizard.as_view(FORMS_DATA, url_name='team_data_step')

urlpatterns = patterns('lending.views',
    url(r'^file/(?P<step>.+)/(?P<project_id>[0-9\-]+)$', login_required(team_wizard), name='team_step_edit'),
```

)

**views.py**

```
FORMS_DATA = [("info", TeamFormInfo),
         ("team_members", TeamFormSet),
         ("social", FundingRequestFormSocial),
         ("documents", FundingRequestFormDocuments), ]
```

The rest of the view is something simple like in the documentation of the django form wizard

**team_step_teammembers.html**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ wizard.management_form }}
  {% if wizard.form.forms %}
      {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
      {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
          {% bootstrap_form form %}
      {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
      {% bootstrap_form wizard.form  %}
  {% endif %}
</form>
```

Django version 1.7.3

Python version 2.7.5

Comment: Try iterating the `wizard.form` instead of `wizard.form.forms`. That should do it..

Comment: @mariodev
Hi, thanks for your help, the error changed now. I get a :

 KeyError at /lending/file/team/3
0

\django\forms\models.py", line 591, in _construct_form
   kwargs['initial'] = self.initial_extra[i - self.initial_form_count()]

On this line :  {% for form in wizard.form %}